# Display data using Oci_fetch_array in an HTML table

Tags: php

I am trying to get print data into an html table using the OCi_FETCH_ARRAY function because I am using Oracle. What I have to do here is show the informations that I have in the database if there is data, otherwise I button to add date shows. 
This is my php code that I am using :

```
    <?php 

    for ($i=1; $i<=4;$i++)
    {
                $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * from SEANCE');
                oci_execute($stid);
                $row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_BOTH);
        echo "<tr><td></td>";        
        for ($j=1; $j<=5;$j++)
            {
            //echo "".$row['DATES']."-".$row['HEURE']."/";
            if($row['ETAT']==1 && $row['DATES']==$j && $row['HEURE']==$i)
               {
                    echo '<td><b>'.$row['ID_INSTRUCTEUR'].'</b><br><i>'.$row['ID_MODULE'].'</i><br>Salle : '.$row['ID_SALLE'].'</td>';
               }
            else
               {
                echo "<td><button class='btn red-bg'  onclick=asd(2,".$j.",".$i.")>Ajouter </button></td>";
               } 
            }
        echo "<tr>";
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
    ?>
```

As you can see I am not able to show all the data, and all what I get is the first element from the array, and I am wondering how can I make this work, to show the whole table correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by saving the data into another array with this way :

```
    <?php 
$array=array(1=>"08:00-9:30",2=>"10:00-11:30",3=>"12:00-13:30",4=>"15:00-16:30");
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT count(IDSEANCE) from SEANCE');
    oci_execute($stid);
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_BOTH);
    //echo $row[0];
    //Verifie rows
    if( $row[0] == 0){
        for ($i=1; $i<=4;$i++)
    {
            echo "<tr><td><b>".$array[$i]."</b></td>"; 

            for ($j=1; $j<=5;$j++){
              echo "<td><button class='btn red-bg'  onclick=asd(2,".$j.",".$i.")>Ajouter </button></td>";
                }
            }
            echo "<tr>";
    } else
    {
    //Problem avec la boucle For.
    $array2=array();
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * from SEANCE where ID_PROGRAMME=' . intval($_GET['idss']) . '');
    oci_execute($stid);
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_BOTH))
    {   
    $array2[$row[5]][$row[4]]="<td><b>".$row['ID_INSTRUCTEUR']."</b><br><i>".$row['ID_MODULE']."</i><br>Salle : ".$row['ID_SALLE']."<button style='background-color:#8DCB79;color:#ffffff;border: 1px solid transparent;float:right;' onclick=asd(2,".$row[4].",".$row[5].")>Modifie </button></td>";
    }
    for ($i=1; $i<=4;$i++)
    {

            echo "<tr><td><b>".$array[$i]."</b></td>"; 

            for ($j=1; $j<=5;$j++)
            {

                if(empty($array2[$i][$j])){
                    $array2[$i][$j] = "<td><button class='btn red-bg'  onclick=asd(2,".$j.",".$i.")>Ajouter </button></td>";

                } 
                echo($array2[$i][$j]);
            }
            echo "<tr>";
    }
    }
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```